# Помогите разбить строчку с помощью split и обработать в JS скрипте

Tags: javascript, ajax, массивы, split

Через AJAX вызывается PHP файл, который возвращает мне числа, разделенные через запятую. Далее мне нужно разбить их на массив и обработать.
Пробовал разные вариации кода, ничего не выходит, что-то упускаю.
Подскажите как поправить?
В `data.parse_cat_list` передаются к примеру данные:

> 27,15,9

Вот мой код

```
var arrmas = data.parse_cat_list;
    arrmas.split(',');

    for(var i=0; i<arrmas.length; i++) {
        $( 'select#category option[value='+arrmas[i]+']' ).attr('selected', 'selected');

    };
```

Comment: Метод [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) возвращает массив, исходная строка при этом не меняется. Поэтому в коде результат `split` теряется, нужно присвоить его чему-нибудь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант

```
var arrmas = data.parse_cat_list.split(',')

$.each(arrmas, function(index, value) {
  $('select#category option[value='+ value +']' ).attr('selected', 'selected');
});
```

Или

```
var arrmas = data.parse_cat_list.split(',');

for(var i=0; i<arrmas.length; i++) {
    $( 'select#category option[value='+arrmas[i]+']' ).attr('selected', 'selected');

};
```

Comment: Первый вариант сработал, второй не пробовал. Вышло)